# List<object> as method argument pass through service proxy between two service call

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have stateless service fabric Azure Applications that one having Method argument as List.
e.g

```
sourceService:
--------------
    List<object> listObject = new List<object>();
     listObject.Add(123);//integer
     listObject.Add("abc");//string
     listObject.Add(listObject);//list of list
     listObject.Add(object);//any object

     serviceproxy.MyMethod(listObject );//service proxy call

destinationService:
------------------
  public async static MyMethod(List<object> listObjects){
   //to do operation on list
   //dynamically parse list based on type serialization and deserialization
  }
```

so how to pass list of objects as argument to one service to another service or may be other way to call,please suggest some way to list parse at service end by pass any type of arguments as method parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must [annotate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-contract-known-types) your data contract with `KnownType` attributes for every element type that can occur inside the list. Otherwise the receiving side does not know which type to create when deserializing the message. The attribute enables the generation of metadata about the contained types.
Check the link for more info.

```cs
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(CircleType))]
[KnownType(typeof(TriangleType))]
public class MyList : List<Shape>
{
    [DataMember]
    public Shape ShapeOfLogo;
}
```